# How to install the Xpand in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, xpand

I m trying to install Xpand in Eclipse. I am doing it through update manager.  However the download stack at around 29%. I use the following link:

http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/m2t/xpand/updates/nightly/

Alternatively I downloaded the zip file from this link:
http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/m2t/downloads/?project=xpand

Then I tried to do install->new software-> Add -> Archive and I pointed at the zip file. I thought that this would gonna work since it uses the local zip file.Again it stucks around 29%.

Now I am thinking to manually add the plug-in to the eclipse but I m not sure how:

The content of the zip are:

```
- binary(folder)
- features(folder)
- plugins(folder)
- artifact.jar
- content.jar
```

I know that I have to copy the features and the plugins folder in the corresponding ones in the eclipse folder. However I don`t know what to do with the binary(folder) and the artifact.jar/content.jar files.

Anybody could help me out please?
Thnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why the installation is getting stuck at 29%.  It may be a firewall/proxy problem on your end, or it may be corrupt metadata in the archive.  It's worth following up on the Xpand mailing list or forum.

But, if you want to install it, you can unzip the archive into your `dropins` folder inside of your eclipse.  This will work unless Xpand requires any third party jars.

Comment: Still I wou;dn't normally recommend this, but seems like something esle is broken.

Answer (score 0):

i use this updatesite for xpand install. and it works well
xpand - http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/m2t/xpand/updates/

go to menu:
help-install new software-(add the link)-select all-finish